# Module not found: Can't resolve './components/counter.jsx' - Why is this failing to compile?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

[image]Following Programming with Mosh's React tutorial and stuck on this very initial portion after installing everything, bootstrap, popper, etc. Deleted package json lock and double checked spelling. For whatever reason no matter what, it is failing to compile and I get the same error every time:

```
"Module not found: Can't resolve './components/counter.jsx'
```

[Picture of my terminal and vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZcUN.png)
[Picture of my errors in dev tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPnyD.png)

I really am stuck on this portion and could use help figuring out what the issue is.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Counter extends Component {
  state = {};
  render() {
    return <h1>Hello World</h1>;
  }
}

export default Counter;
```

Comment: show counter.jsx file, also you can try saving it as .js file

Comment: the bottom code on my submission is my counter file within a components folder within src where index.js is also located.

Comment: why don't you save it as .js

Comment: it's saved as a jsx file in the tutorial though, do we not need to have it as a jsx file for react?

Comment: not at all, just save it as a .js file

Answer (score 1):

In his tutorial he has changed the JSX file name from counter.jsx to counterComponent.jsx. Import as below:

```
import Counter from './components/counterComponent'
```

Answer (score -1):

When importing components and other javascript modules, you shouldn't provide the file extension. Try and remove the `.jsx` from the import so it says:

```
import Counter from "./components/counter";
```

Comment: I did that initially but it did not work. Still not working without jsx tacked on.

Comment: What version of `create-react-app` are you using?

Comment: "dependencies": {
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.2.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "boostrap": "^2.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "jquery": "^1.9.1",
    "npm": "^6.14.4",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3"

I just typed 
npm i -g create-react-app into my terminal, i did not specify 1.5.2 like Mosh

Comment: Okay, that seems really odd. CRA supports both .js and .jsx files out of the box, so it should work as expected. Have you tried changing the extension of counter.jsx to counter.js instead as @mehta-rohan mentioned?

Comment: It's supposed to be a react file though isnt it?

Comment: if i move counter to be in the src file rather than within a file within src file, it works. Why can it not work if i have it within another folder?

Comment: It seems very weird. It's also very strange that the other modules like `./App` or `./serviceWorker` gets imported without any issues. Have you tried creating other modules? Maybe there is a hidden typo or some weird character with the path or the module, which might cause the error. Try creating a new test component in the root of the `src` folder, and see if you can import and render that.